# Efficient calculation of diagonal matrix elements

Tags: linear-algebra, performance-tuning

I have a matrix $V$  of size $M$ in which each row $i$ is a vector $v_i$. Now I have another matrix $H$ and I would like to calculate as efficiently as possible the list of values  $v_i^\dagger\cdot H\cdot v_i$ for $i \in 1\ldots M$. I tried using Thread but I couldn't figure out how to do it.

Thank you in advance for any insight.

Answer (score 4):

`Thread` is the inappropriate tool here as it does not hold its arguments, i.e. it does not have the attribute `HoldAll`:

```
Attributes@Thread
(* {Protected} *)
```

So, `ConjugateTranspose[v].H.v` evaluates before `Thread` can operate on it. Also, `Thread` will attempt to thread across `H`, as well, which is clearly not what you want. The correct tool to use here is `Map`:

```
Conjugate[#].H.#& /@ v
```

where `v` is the list containing your basis vectors.

**Edit**: Sometimes you look at one of your own answers and wonder why you are doing it the hard way, and using `Map` is most definitely the hard way. It is functionally correct, but it can be made simpler. First, we need to understand how vector multiplication is interpreted by *Mathematica* to ensure we get it right. When you enter

```
H.v
```

it is interpreted as

$$\pmatrix{H_{11} & H_{12} & \cdots \\ H_{11} & H_{12} & \cdots \\ \vdots & \vdots & \ddots}.\pmatrix{v_1 \\ v_2 \\ \vdots}$$

and

```
v.H
```

is interpreted as $v^{T}\cdot H$. So, if you have a list of vectors that you want to left multiply by a matrix, you must `Transpose` the list. So, using

```
H = {{1, 0, I}, {0, 3, 0}, {-I, 0, 1}};
{evals, evecs} = Eigensystem@H
(* {{3, 2, 0}, {{0, 1, 0}, {I, 0, 1}, {-I, 0, 1}}} *)
```

as our input, to get $v_i^\dagger \cdot H \cdot v_i$, we use

```
With[{v = Transpose@Orthogonalize@evecs},
 ConjugateTranspose[v].H.v
]
(* {{3, 0, 0}, {0, 2, 0}, {0, 0, 0}} *)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The Map method does not have the efficiency I was looking for. I wonder if one can do better.

Comment: Define efficiently. For large enough lists of vectors, `Map` auto compiles, and `Dot` and `Conjugate` are on the [list of functions](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/1101/52) that are compilable. This won't give a speed boost, though, if the matrix or vectors are symbolic. Are they?